# Not able to figure how this groovy closure works

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and was reading a testcase where I found the following:

```
def temp = {
        def temp = new HashMap()
        temp.clear()
        temp.set('A', '1')
        temp.set('B', '2')
        temp
    }
```

I wanted to know what value will the temp variable hold at the end of the definition since its used in a test case

```
assert Blah.blah(temp())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be analogous to the map `[ A:1, B:2 ]`.

Your assert line calls `temp()` which returns that map and then passes it to the `Blah.blah` method

You could rewrite the whole closure as:

```
def temp = { -> [ A:1, B:2 ] as HashMap }
```

And if a LinkedHashMap would do, you can even leave off the `as HashMap` bit